# spark-ml unlabeled data scoring

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata

EDITED: For data with label, we can use LabeledPoint for training and testing. However, if I have a dataframe of unlabeled data, what's the best way to find the probability of it belongs to which class(suppose binary classification)?

Suppose the dataframe looks like

# of DataPoint | Feature 1 | Feature 2 | ... |Feature 1000|

while the dimension of features is the same to that of LabeledPoints in training. All the code is in Scala with Spark 2.x.

Comment: What do you want to use _"to score those data"_? What's the ML algorithm (aka estimator)?

Comment: To score data according to what ? You need to be the one who's the define the score function.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! Just to say I'm using logistic regression to do binary classification. I'd hope to have the probability of the datapoint belongs to 0/1.